# Vuetify: adjust bottom margin on input fields depending on visibility of (error)message

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

In Vuetify 2.0 is it possible to have less bottom margin on input fields (`v-input__control`) in case the `v-messages__wrapper` is empty?

So I need less bottom margin when it's like this:

```
<div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
        <div class="v-messages theme--light">
            <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And more when it's like this:

```
<div class="v-input__control">
    <div class="v-input__slot">...</div>
    <div class="v-text-field__details">
        <div class="v-messages theme--light">
            <div class="v-messages__wrapper"><div class="v-messages__message">Mandatory field</div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've been experimenting with `div.v-messages__wrapper:empty` but there is not much I can do to this div to decrease the bottom margin. As far as I can tell the only way to decrease the margin is to either set `display: none` or a negative margin on `div.v-text-field__details` but this class doesn't know there is no inner content.

Are there any options to accomplish this (preferably with css)?

Answer (score 0):

I had also run into a similar situation.

I noticed that when error messages were raised, `error--text` class was added to the input divs. So, I added a style:-

```
<style>

.error--text {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

</style>
```

Now, whenever the errors were raised, a `margin-bottom` of `10 px` was applied and fixed my issue.